# Execute Reader: Connection Property has not been initialized in C# and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I keep getting the error

> ExecuteReader: Connection Property has not been initialized

in C# and Visual Studio. I have tried some solutions that I researched but they do not seem to be doing the trick.

Here is my code:

```
public static int AddCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = MySqlCommand.GetConnection();

    string strInsertStatement =
            "INSERT Customers (Name, Address, City, State, ZipCode) " +
            "VALUES (@Name, @Address, @City, @State, @ZipCode)";

    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand insertCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strInsertStatement);

    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", customer.strFirstName);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", customer.strStreetName);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", customer.strCity);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", customer.strState);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", customer.strPhoneNumber);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string strSelectStatement = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Customers') FROM Customers";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSelectStatement, connection);

        int customerID = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
        return customerID;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

What am I missing that is making this error appear?

Comment: You're using `MySqlConnection` and `MySqlCommand` which indicates **MySQL** as your RDBMS - but everything else, the syntax of your parameters (`@ZipCode`) and the use of `IDENT_CURRENT` seem to point to Microsoft **SQL Server** - so which one do you *really* want to talk to here?????

Comment: This is for a class assignment. The in class example that my prof gave us to base this off of was a SQL server example but I am supposed to be connecting to MySQL server. I was trying to reuse some of the code from the in class example except I honestly have no clue as to make it work for MySQL server considering we only learned with SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all: Connection Property has not been set.

You have a Connection, and you have insertCommand. Nowhere in the code are you telling insertCommand to use the Connection.

```
insertCommand.Connection = connection;
```

Or, possibly, as part of its connector as you do with the Select.

Comment: Where in the code would I need to insert this solution? Where I was thinking did not work.

Comment: Well, three other answers suggest using the constructor, so maybe go with that, heh. Otherwise, you'd just set the property somewhere before you call `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the connection as second parameter to   MySQlCommand:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand insertCommand =
            new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strInsertStatement, connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

In which line do you get the error? I just had a quick look at your code and think you forgot to add your connection to the insert command use the following instead:

**EDIT:** Put all the code here and added printing of error to console and assignment of connection.

I guess you get your error in the open() method call. There is no connect string in your solution. Don't forget to enter your credentials.

```
public static int AddCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;" +
        "pwd=12345;database=test;"
    string strInsertStatement =
        "INSERT Customers " +
        "(Name, Address, City, State, ZipCode) " +
        "VALUES (@Name, @Address, @City, @State, @ZipCode)";
    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand insertCommand =
        new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strInsertStatement);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
        "@Name", customer.strFirstName);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
        "@Address", customer.strStreetName);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
        "@City", customer.strCity);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
        "@State", customer.strState);
    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(
        "@ZipCode", customer.strPhoneNumber);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        insertCommand.Connection = connection;
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string strSelectStatement =
            "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Customers') FROM Customers";
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand selectCommand =
            new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strSelectStatement, connection);
        int customerID = Convert.ToInt32(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
        return customerID;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this fix and it doesn't seem to be doing the trick. How am I able to find which line the error is in?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Connection property of the command. Use the constructor that accepts a MySqlConnection.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand insertCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strInsertStatement, connection);
```